# How to get the default WebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need the context to `ApplicationContext.xml` ,which I provided in `web.xml` as

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

But I need a control for this in `Controller` class.

I tried many things including

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
```

but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use [`getWebApplicationContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) of `WebApplicationContextUtils`:

> Find the root WebApplicationContext
>   for this web application, which is
>   typically loaded via
>   ContextLoaderListener.

See also [`getRequiredWebApplicationContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getRequiredWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29).

Answer (score 0):

**RequestContextUtils** will be the best choice as, even if you have multiple WebAppContexts it will get the current active one.