# injecting directly to servlet instead of new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I have a big java project that contains many servlets. and each servlet needs 
to get objects from the same bean file using the following command:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

and then I use

```
     context.getBean("<BEAN_NAME">);
```

some of them even needs to get same objects.

the question is if it's possible to inject the object that I want directly to the servlets without reading the bean file manually.

each servlet is configured in web.xml.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a web application, I would go with a `WebApplicationContext` contained in `spring-web`, which is loaded at deploy-time of your web application and properly closed on undeploy. All you have to do is declaring the `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then you can access your `ApplicationContext` from any servlet:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
    .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) ctx.getBean("myBean");
myBean.doSomething();
```

The advantage is, that your context is shared between all servlets.

**References:**

- [How to get the default WebApplicationContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495741/how-to-get-the-default-webapplicationcontext)
- [Integration of ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#web-integration-common)
- [WebApplicationContextUtils Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getRequiredWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29)

Comment: i don't understand what is the MyBeans class. before i just use ApplicationContext to get the bean. now I need to create a class for it ?

Comment: or maybe i'm missing something.. ctx.getBean gets the bean itself and not the bean.xml file ?

Comment: ahah ok.. so how do i tell it exactly to which bean file to go to ?

Comment: @ufk: I edited the answer to include that part from Spring documentation. Specify the location of the XML/XMLs via `contextConfigLocation` `context-param`.

Comment: ohhhh not as complicated as i thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered having your servlets implement [HttpRequestHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html)?

You then have to declare your Servlet as named Spring bean and use the same name on web.xml, then you can simply use the @Autowired annotation to injection your Spring beans in your Servlet

More info at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/251636/How-to-inject-Spring-beans-into-Servlets

Sample Code:

```
  @Component("myServlet") 
   public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

        @Autowired
        private MyService myService;
...
```

sample web.xml

```
<servlet>     
            <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
            <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet
           </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/myurl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just use a `DispatcherServlet` and the full Spring MVC suite then?

Comment: yeah i googled that first before posting the question. had problems understanding that AutoWired functionality. i'm used to injecting with xml configuration. not with code annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SerlvetContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) with the `Servlet#init()` method. When your servlet container creates a servlet context, it will call `contextInitialized()` on any `ServletContextListener`s where you can do initialization of application singletons/beans/etc.

```
public class YourServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // clear context
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // initialize spring context    
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("context", springContext);
    }
}
```

All Servlets within this context (servlet context) will have access to these attributes.

In the Servlet `init()` method, you just get the attribute

```
public class YourServlet implements Servlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        config.getServletContext().getAttribute("context");
        // cast it (the method returns Object) and use it
    }

    // more
}
```

Comment: with @nif and your answer i can come up with some kind of a solution. checking it now. thanks